# Try to show nav only if I'm on the homepage of a wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show a navigation only if a user is on a wordpress homepage. I read the documentation on [wordpress conditionals](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), and it looks like is_home is the appropriate way to do this? I am normally not tasked with doing this sort of thing, so any help is really appreciated!

**Note: This did not work for me**

Here is my code:

```
<?php if (is_home()) { ?>
<ul class="nav sf-js-enabled" style="display: none;" id="filters">
  <li class="current_page_item">
    <a href="http://make.truliablog.com" data-filter="*" style="text-indent: 0px;">Home</a>
  </li>                                                        <li class="cat-item cat-item-30">
    <a title="View all posts filed under Database" href="http://make.truliablog.com/category/database/" data-filter=".database" style="text-indent: 0px;">Database</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<?php   }?>
```

Comment: Yes, `is_home()` should do the trick. You've posted that code but haven't indicated if it worked or not. What's the question?

Comment: oh I'm sorry this did not work for me. Thank you for the response!

Comment: Can you elaborate on "did not work"? Did you get an error?

Comment: Yeah sorry ceejayoz, the associated html just did not display. When I included the word "TEST" it did however show up, which leads me to believe I do not understand how html should be formatted when between php tags or something?

Comment: Does the HTML show up in the source code? If so, the likely culprit is the `display: none;` bit.

Comment: oh duh I can't believe I missed that. You're awesome! That'll work for sure. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Use `is_front_page()` it should work if you have a static page set as the front page.

Answer (score 0):

As we figured out via the comments, the `display: none` is your issue. :-)